# LT4320 Ideal Diode Bridge Controller - supply voltage max ratings reference point

Tags: linear, bridge-rectifier

The [LT4320](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4320fb.pdf) and MOSFET bridge was suggested as a low dropout bridge rectifier in another post. I hadn't come across it before so I investigated further.

[image]

I'm puzzled by the IN1, IN2 maximum ratings.

[image]

What point is being used as reference for these input voltages?

---

Duh!

As the Dave's answer and Brian's comment point out, the answer is in the notes which I missed on the next page. Let this post stand as a reminder to others to read the notes!

Comment: Notes 1 and 2 might explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the footnotes:

> **Note 2:** All voltages are referenced to OUTN = 0V unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Yup. That's what I thought but missed the footnote on the next page. Thanks. I presume that this should never happen in practice if the MOSFETs are all in place and working.